# Is it possible to organize PPPoE server for lan clients with Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012

I need my server 2012 to work as a pppoe server for lan clients. Google says I need Linux. Is there no way to do that with windows?

Comment: See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/103b825d-cb57-429d-8a42-a2e88e290ea0/windows-2008-rras-with-pppoe-dial-on-demand and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753085(WS.10).aspx